# Django-piston make piston return full traceback of exception

Tags: django, django-piston

How to make piston return full traceback of exception. By default it returns me only last error text. Like

```
id() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
```

Need to know which file and which line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piston loads a http status response via `utils.rc`, no errors are raised.

from the documentation:

```
Configuration variables
Piston is configurable in a couple of ways, which allows more granular 
control of some areas without editing the code.

Setting                         Meaning
settings.PISTON_EMAIL_ERRORS    If (when) Piston crashes, it will email the 
                                administrators a backtrace (like the Django one
                                you see during DEBUG = True)
settings.PISTON_DISPLAY_ERRORS  Upon crashing, will display a small backtrace 
                                to the client, including the method signature 
                                expected.
settings.PISTON_STREAM_OUTPUT   When enabled, Piston will instruct Django to 
                                stream the output to the client, but please read
                                streaming before enabling it.
```

I'd recommend to setup a logger, [sentry](http://sentry.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) together with [raven](http://raven.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config/django.html) is rather convenient and you get to configure your own log level and handler.